# Can I say "She can distinguish her baby's cry from others'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions, sentence

Is it OK to say this way? Or should I say "She has the ability to distinguish her baby's cry from that of others."? In this sentence she has the ability to identify the particular cry of her own baby.

Comment: You can use either, but either way the sentence as a whole is very technical and cold. It may well appear in a scientific paper, but in everyday conversation a native speaker is extremely unlikely to produce it.

Comment: She can tell when it's her baby that's crying.

Comment: Is the possessive pronoun  used  here <from others'  > then OK in this sentence?

Comment: @Ian54 Your example doesn't work, because the two sentences are different (distinguish   baby's cry _from_ others, train travelling faster _than_ others). 'Faster than that of other trains' makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'd say she can *Easily* distinguish her baby's cry from others. Most mothers can.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is an example of [noun ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Nominal_ellipsis).

*She can distinguish her baby's cry from others' cries.* -->
*She can distinguish her baby's cry from others' [ ].*

However, I don't think that's what you mean to say. As constructed, your sentence could be comparing her baby's cry to, for example, the cries of elephants or doves.

I think you mean this:

*She can distinguish her baby's cry from other babies' cries.* -->
*She can distinguish her baby's cry from other babies' [ ].*

Your best bet is to rewrite without a possessive apostrophe:

*She can distinguish her baby's cry from those of other babies.*